# What does `status: :ok` do in `render json:` (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

What does`status: :ok` do in `render json: {round: @round}, status: :ok`?

Sometimes everything works without it, but sometimes its necessary to prevent an error like,

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
```

I use Angular for front-end and Rails for back-end.

My understanding is that this final line in the Rails controller action converts the server response  back to `json` format so Angular can read it (not 100% confident this is correct explanation).

But I don't understand why to use one or the other of the following. Sometimes one works and sometimes the other does.

1. `render json: {round: @round}, status: :ok1`
2. `respond_to :json` and `respond_with @round`

Can anyone share some insight?

Comment: Status ok: is just a key value pair with your json indicating the success of request, it should not a madatory field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `status: :ok` in `render json: {round: @round}, status: :ok` tells the `render` method to change the status code which is `200 OK` by default in the HTTP header ([Rendering in Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option)). So in case of `:ok` there should be no difference.

Your method invocation tells the `render` method to render the hash `{round: @round}` in json format with the status code `200 OK`.

The [api dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to) tells you more about the usage of `respond_to` which is used to distinguish between different content types while `render` does the heavy lifting of actually rendering your response.

Answer (score 8):

> What does `status: :ok` do in `render json:`

It means the response will be sent with `200 OK` http response code.